# Force StreamPlot to stay within region

Tags: plotting

`StreamPlot` likes to sample points outside the plot region.  For example,

```
res = Reap[StreamPlot[{Sqrt[x], y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
  EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y}]]];
Show[res[[1]], ListPlot[res[[2]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As in this example, this is typically not a problem.  However, I have some numerically defined functions that are not well defined outside the region, which I'd like `StreamPlot` to avoid.  Is there an option or other trick to force `StreamPlot` to not evaluate outside the plot region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `ConditionalExpression`:

```
res = Reap[StreamPlot[
        ConditionalExpression[{Sqrt[x], y}, 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1], 
    {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y}], StreamStyle -> Pink]];
Show[res[[1]], ListPlot[res[[2]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Gave it a little more thought & came up with a workable solution based on `Condition (/;)`:

```
f[x_, y_] := Sqrt[x] /; (0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1);
g[x_, y_] := y /; (0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1);

res = Reap[StreamPlot[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
  EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y}], StreamStyle -> Pink]];
Show[res[[1]], ListPlot[res[[2]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]